# Can't make menu navbar dropdown

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't make a menu navbar dropdown, here's my code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="technology.html">tech</a>
    </li>

    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown">case <span class="caret"></span></a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">In</a>
        </li>
        <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" href="#">Out</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="staff.html">staff</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="gallery.html">gallery</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to make the case become a dropdown menu, but I can't make the menu items "in" and "out" appear, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What program are you using?

Comment: html, i use bootstrap, i edit on notepad++

Comment: Check all bootstrap CSS and JS files are loaded?

Comment: Check if there's an error occuring, from what i see, it should work.

Comment: @AmitG all is loaded, i can send my code if you want

Comment: @AltayMazlum it run, with no error, but the dropdown cant appear thats why i was confuse :(

Comment: Did you load jQuery before bootstrap.js?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your scripts might not have properly loaded. I tested your codes and they work just fine. I only added the following lines to load the required files from external sources:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

[image: Test]

Comment: wow, thanks man, it works after i copied your external sources